# How to displace DIV container when menu is toggled

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have [this code](http://bulma.io/documentation/components/nav/) based on [Bulma CSS framework](http://bulma.io/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("is-active");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="nav-item">
      <strong>LOGO</strong>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- This "nav-toggle" hamburger menu is only visible on mobile -->
  <!-- You need JavaScript to toggle the "is-active" class on "nav-menu" -->
  <span class="nav-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </span>

  <!-- This "nav-menu" is hidden on mobile -->
  <!-- Add the modifier "is-active" to display it on mobile -->
  <div class="nav-right nav-menu">
    <a class="nav-item">
      Home
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Info
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Contact
    </a>

  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt harum corporis nobis cupiditate minima cum quisquam fugiat, laudantium optio est ex itaque molestias alias tempore laboriosam in quae numquam quas.</p>
</div>
```

When `.nav-toggle` is clicked the `.container` is covered by `.nav-menu`.

How can `.container` would be displaced as `.nav-menu` is showed/displayed?

*Note: If you can't see the hamburguer menu try to resize the browser window.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood. However it is a hack and not so nice, but works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("is-active");
    if ($(".nav-menu").hasClass("is-active")) {
      $(".container").css('margin-top', $(".nav-menu").height() + 'px');
    } else {
      $(".container").css('margin-top', '0px');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="nav-item">
      <strong>LOGO</strong>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- This "nav-toggle" hamburger menu is only visible on mobile -->
  <!-- You need JavaScript to toggle the "is-active" class on "nav-menu" -->
  <span class="nav-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </span>

  <!-- This "nav-menu" is hidden on mobile -->
  <!-- Add the modifier "is-active" to display it on mobile -->
  <div class="nav-right nav-menu">
    <a class="nav-item">
      Home
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Info
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Contact
    </a>

  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt harum corporis nobis cupiditate minima cum quisquam fugiat, laudantium optio est ex itaque molestias alias tempore laboriosam in quae numquam quas.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with `absolute` you need to calculate the menu `height` and then toggle and increase that much `margin-top` of `container`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("is-active");
    $(".container").toggleClass("contaianerShift");
  });
});
```

```css
.contaianerShift {
 margin-top:160px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="nav-item">
      <strong>LOGO</strong>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- This "nav-toggle" hamburger menu is only visible on mobile -->
  <!-- You need JavaScript to toggle the "is-active" class on "nav-menu" -->
  <span class="nav-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </span>

  <!-- This "nav-menu" is hidden on mobile -->
  <!-- Add the modifier "is-active" to display it on mobile -->
  <div class="nav-right nav-menu">
    <a class="nav-item">
      Home
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Info
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Contact
    </a>

  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt harum corporis nobis cupiditate minima cum quisquam fugiat, laudantium optio est ex itaque molestias alias tempore laboriosam in quae numquam quas.</p>
</div>
```